# Filtrado por Rol genera una recursion infinita

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jhipster

**Un poco de contexto**

Estoy aprendiendo Angular, Java, y Jhipster, trato de filtrar los usuarios por rol pero al hacerlo estoy teniendo un error de Stack Overflow.

Este es el error que genera mi `consola`

```
    2019-03-22 14:08:32.082  WARN 12044 --- [  XNIO-2 task-9] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain:["extendedUser"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.ExtendedUser["usuario"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.User["extendedUser"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.ExtendedUser["usuario"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.User["extendedUser"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.ExtendedUser["usuario"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.User["extendedUser"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.ExtendedUser["usuario"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.User["extendedUser"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.ExtendedUser["usuario"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.User["extendedUser"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.ExtendedUser["usuario"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.User["extendedUser"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.ExtendedUser["usuario"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.User["extendedUser"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.ExtendedUser["usuario"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.User["extendedUser"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.ExtendedUser["usuario"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.User["extendedUser"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.ExtendedUser["usuario"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.User["extendedUser"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.ExtendedUser["usuario"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.User["extendedUser"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.ExtendedUser["usuario"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.User["extendedUser"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.ExtendedUser["usuario"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.User["extendedUser"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.ExtendedUser["usuario"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.User["extendedUser"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.ExtendedUser["usuario"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.User["extendedUser"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.ExtendedUser["usuario"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.User["extendedUser"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.ExtendedUser["usuario"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.User["extendedUser"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.ExtendedUser["usuario"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.User["extendedUser"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.ExtendedUser["usuario"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.User["extendedUser"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.ExtendedUser["usuario"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.User["extendedUser"]
```

este es mi **userRepository.java**

```
@Query(value = "select user from User user inner join user.authorities authorities where authorities.name =:role")
List<User> findByRole(@Param("role") String role);
```

Estoy tratando de hacker un inner join entre  la tabla user y  la tabla  user_authority estoy pasando el nombre del rol com una String "ROLE_ADMIN".

Esta es el `DTO` de extended User que es donde creo se genera el error:

```
/**
 * A DTO for the ExtendedUser entity.
 */
public class ExtendedUserDTO extends UserDTO implements Serializable {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExtendedUserDTO.class);
    private Long id;

    private String puesto;

    private BigDecimal sueldo;

    private LocalDate fechaIngreso;

    private Long usuarioId;

    //private Long coordinadorId;

    private Set<Area> areas = new HashSet<>();


    private Long coordinadorId;

    private String coordinadorLogin;


    private User coordinador;

    private Set<Desarrollo> desarrollos = new HashSet<>();

    public ExtendedUserDTO(){

    }

    public ExtendedUserDTO(User user){
        super(user);
        this.puesto = user.getExtendedUser().getPuesto();
        this.sueldo = user.getExtendedUser().getSueldo();
        this.fechaIngreso = user.getExtendedUser().getFechaIngreso();
        this.id = user.getId();
        this.usuarioId = user.getId();
        this.coordinadorLogin = user.getExtendedUser().getCoordinador().getLogin();
        this.coordinadorId = user.getExtendedUser().getCoordinador().getId();
        this.coordinador = user.getExtendedUser().getCoordinador();
        Hibernate.initialize(user.getExtendedUser().getAreas());
        this.areas = user.getExtendedUser().getAreas();
        Hibernate.initialize(user.getExtendedUser().getDesarrollos());
        this.desarrollos = user.getExtendedUser().getDesarrollos();

    }
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPuesto() {
        return puesto;
    }

    public void setPuesto(String puesto) {
        this.puesto = puesto;
    }

    public BigDecimal getSueldo() {
        return sueldo;
    }

    public void setSueldo(BigDecimal sueldo) {
        this.sueldo = sueldo;
    }

    public LocalDate getFechaIngreso() {
        return fechaIngreso;
    }

    public void setFechaIngreso(LocalDate fechaIngreso) {
        this.fechaIngreso = fechaIngreso;
    }

    public Long getUsuarioId() {
        return usuarioId;
    }

    public void setUsuarioId(Long userId) {
        this.usuarioId = userId;
    }

    /* public void setCoordinadorId(Long userId) {
        this.coordinadorId = userId;
    }

    public Long getCoordinadorId() {
        return coordinadorId;
    }*/


    public User getCoordinador() {
        return coordinador;
    }

    public void setCoordinador(User user) {
        this.coordinador = user;
    }


    public Set<Area> getAreas() {
        return areas;
    }

    public void setAreas(Set<Area> areas) {
        this.areas = areas;
    }

    public Set<Desarrollo> getDesarrollos() {
        return desarrollos;
    }

    public void setDesarrollos(Set<Desarrollo> desarrollos) {
        this.desarrollos = desarrollos;
    }

    public Long getCoordinadorId() {
        return coordinadorId;
    }

    public void setCoordinadorId(Long userId) {
        this.coordinadorId = userId;
    }

    public String getCoordinadorLogin() {
        return coordinadorLogin;
    }

    public void setCoordinadorLogin(String userLogin) {
        this.coordinadorLogin = userLogin;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        ExtendedUserDTO extendedUserDTO = (ExtendedUserDTO) o;
        if (extendedUserDTO.getId() == null || getId() == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return Objects.equals(getId(), extendedUserDTO.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(getId());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ExtendedUserDTO{" +
            "id=" + getId() +
            ", puesto='" + getPuesto() + "'" +
            ", sueldo=" + getSueldo() +
            ", fechaIngreso='" + getFechaIngreso() + "'" +
            ", usuario=" + getUsuarioId() +
            ", coordinador='" + getCoordinadorLogin() + "'" +
            "}";
    }
}
```

Lo que creo que podría generar el problema

Dentro de usuarios tengo una relación 1 a 1 con otra entidad llamada extendedUser que es una entidad para complementar datos del usuario, esta entidad tiene una relación llamada coordinador con usuarios nuevamente, así que creo que eso podría estar causando la recursion.

pues sí en la consulta en lugar de llamar al modelo hago esto: s`elect user.login` en lugar de  `select users` ya no tengo el problema de la recursion infinita.

**Notas**

- Soy muy nuevo en Angular, Jhipster y Java, si omite información
  importante por favor hazmelo saber en los comentarios y lo agregan.
- Solo estoy tratando de obtener los usuarios que cumplen con cierto
  ROL si tiene una mejor solución me encararía saberla.

Comment: Deberías poner la clase User, para entender un poco mejor el problema, junto con el stacktrace

Comment: @PabloLozano hola gracias, lo acabo de añadir a la pregunta.

Answer (score -1):

hay una tabla intermedia entre User y Rol, JHI_USER_AUTHORITY  es una tea, partiendo de ahi podrias obtener los usuarios que tengan un rol en especifico.